# How to achieve slideToggle effect similar to facebook "New Stories" button with jQuery?

Tags: facebook, toggle, jquery

As you may know not long time ago facebook added several new features. One of them was a "New Stories" button which when clicked expands (with what I guess is a slideToggle effect) and shows new stories.

---

**Here is the button I am talking about:**

[image: FaceBook toogle Button]

---

I would like to know How to achieve same slide / toggle effect and fade in effect that comes in after this button is clicked, with a help of jQuery.

I tried searching for this on internet, but all effects I found were regular slideToggle effects, I mean they started showing div from top and slided down to it's bottom (here is what I mean by regular content http://jsfiddle.net/TwxB4/), where as one facebook uses starts from the bottom of the hidden div and sort of slides to the top of it. (You will see what I mean if you check it on facebook).

**Edit:** I am only looking for a slideToggle effect and nothing else, I want to be abble to expand and shrink hidden div when user clicks on the link that lunches the effect.

---

**Edit:** Here is an illustration of the effect I'm looking for:

[image: illustration]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example works the way you described, showing bottom content first:

http://jsfiddle.net/SBLNn/16/

Also full screen view here:

http://jsfiddle.net/SBLNn/16/embedded/result/

They may also do it by having the overflow of the feed hidden, and then setting a negative margin on the inner feed wrapper, then when you click they just animate that negative margin down to 0.

Comment: Great this is exactly what I was looking for, just one thing is it possible to make it so it also hides it when the link is clicked again?

Comment: Yes, for sure.. here is an updated version that will toggle the show / hide: http://jsfiddle.net/SBLNn/17/

Answer (score 1):

Does this works for you 
http://jsfiddle.net/wb7h6/1/

updated  version
http://jsfiddle.net/wb7h6/9/ I hope this is what you need

Comment: Not really I don't think so, What I want to use it for is to expand one hidden div that contains information in it. in your example each message expands with a regularToggle function (from top to bottom), Basically what I need is a slideToggle function that expands from bottom to top, can you understand what I mean? Thank You for the answer anyway it is something new for me ))

Comment: Ok, so slide down means literally prepped new content with slide effect from top to down each time somone clicks "Test Text" ? And no ajax, just content in page?

Comment: Yes )) but like in the illustration, where the content that is at the bottom appears first sliding down and displaying more content that is located towards the top of the page. Like in illustration )) And yes no ajax, the content is already on page, just hidden ))

Comment: Yes hidden content at the bottom has priority, it first shows, then on next click it will go to next hidden content most bottom and slide it down... Also there is a link "animate all" it automates all process, it will automatically slide one by one until all hidden paragraphs re shown.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I didn't explain it well enough, It is not suppose to act on several different paragraphs. Here if you visit this website I found http://webintersect.com/ And click on one of the links, you can see how it slides down to show hidden content. This is what I need, but a little bit differently. The main difference would be that when it starts sliding down the first content that appeaser is the one at the bottom not at the top like in example. I am so sory for making it so confusing it's just that english is not my first language.

Comment: Exactly, what I need is same effect that you get when you click on section 4 in the demo you provided. See how it expands conntent from bottom to top? I am looking for the same effect, but so it doesn't slide up while it is expanding. is it supported in jQuery UI? I don't need full accordion functionality just the slide effect same as in section 4, to expand one hidden <div> on my website. Is that possible with jQuery UI?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4675/discussion-between-milan-jaric-and-ilya-knaup)

Answer (score 0):

You want `slideToggle()` I think.  See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TwxB4/).

Comment: This is what I meant when I was talking about regular effects. See how it starts from the top and slides down, but on facebook it starts by showing content that is at the bottom and slides down til it reaches the top content. Do you see what I mean? Thnx for answer I'll use it as addition to my question. ))